# Removing hash extension from cargo dylib naming

Tags: shared-libraries, rust, rust-cargo

**Cargo.toml**

```
[lib]
name = "faceblaster-engine"
crate_type = ["dylib"]
```

Whenever I execute `cargo build` my dylib is named:

`libfaceblaster-engine-f09635dc7c9bd155.so`.

Is there anyway to add something to the `.toml` file to remove the hash being placed on the end?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you want to remove the hash?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I guess just for consistency sake with the rest of my libs dir.  If for any reason, it ever changes, I would really hate to go through and adjust anything that needs that hash change, but unaware of what would cause the hash to change.

Comment: What about just having a build step (somewhere) that does `cp target/release/mylib-*.so libs/mylib.so`?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I'd be interested in how to get the version number instead of the hash. For example, I have `libpng.dylib`, `libpng16.dylib`, and `libpng16.16.dylib` installed. I'd like to be able to create libraries that fit in with the rest of the ecosystem.

Comment: I've got that as a build step now, just wondering if there was a way to get rid of it, but I am guessing I'm stuck with running a bash command on it at some point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hash is the result of a bunch of metadata, which, IIRC, includes the version of the Rust compiler used to make it. Because Rust does not have a defined ABI, you can only use this library with the exact same SHA of the compiler which was used to make it. Erasing this data would erase your ability to know if you can actually successfully use it or not.

Comment: Unless the compiler checks against the name first, I don't think there is a way to tell until you get linker errors?  `rustc --version` doesn't show anything near that hash?  And at that point, it doesn't seem useful in the name unless there is a way to tell before linking?  I'm linking it with a C++ shim, so I have C ABI exposing core entry functions of use...

Comment: It's more than just the version, there's other information as well.